# How to add a dashed underlined label on Graphviz?

Tags: format, graphviz, dot

I would like to have a dashed underlined label on Graphviz, like the image bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-automatic solution is to write underlines manually:

```
partial_key_attribute [label = <<u>P</u>A<u>R</u>T<u>I</u>A<u>L</u> <u>K</u>E<u>Y</u><br/><u>A</u>T<u>T</u>R<u>I</u>B<u>U</u>T<u>E</u>>];
```

[image]

Although ugly, at least this works with most kinds of use cases, although some preprocessing might be needed to make this more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

An answer would be to use Unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_below but it wouldn't work with all fonts and is super bad for users to type and looks ugly too.